# WaitForExit () remains don't finish

Tags: c#, postgresql

```
public void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackupDatabase(
            "localhost",
            "5432",
            "postgres",
            "***********",
            "PerfectFreight",
            txtPath.Text,
            "Backup #",
            "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\13\\bin\\");
    }
    public static string BackupDatabase(
        string server,
        string port,
        string user,
        string password,
        string dbname,
        string backupdir,
        string backupFileName,
        string backupCommandDir)
    { 
        try
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", password);

            string backupFile = backupdir + backupFileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "_Time»" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH") + ";" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm") + ".backup";

            string BackupString = " -U " + user + " -h " + server + " -p " + port + " -d " + dbname + " -F c -b -v -f \"" + backupFile;

            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = backupCommandDir + "\\pg_dump.exe";

            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = BackupString;

            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;//for error checks BackupString
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;//use for not opening cmd screen
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;//use for not opening cmd screen

            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Backup successfully created");


            return backupFile;

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The program starts to run but does not finish, it does not give an error. In the instruction `proc.WaitForExit();` the execution gets stuck as in an infinite loop.

Comment: Presumably `pg_dump.exe` doesn't exit.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to provide sample of code that mimics the program that your code tries to run  along with simplified version of code that calls `Process.Start`. So far there is no reason to believe the behavior is wrong as everything point to started exe just not finishing (i.e. waiting on input/output).

Comment: Add `proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`. It looks like you're missing a double-quote after "BackupFile". Should be `string BackupString = " -U " + user + " -h " + server + " -p " + port + " -d " + dbname + " -F c -b -v -f \"" + backupFile + "\"";` To add "PGPASSWORD" as an environment variable, do the following: `proc.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"] = password;`

Comment: When you redirect output but *don't* read the output then the program will just hang when its output buffers fill up.  Since you redirect both stdout and stderr, you must use the BeginXxxxReadLine() methods.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `pg_dump` will turn out as

```
-U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d PerfectFreight -F c -b -v -f "...Backup #02_05_2021_Time»10;32.backup
```

Apart from the crazy file name, there are some serious problems with that:

- you forgot the closing double quote in the end
- the option `-v` does *not* mean "verbose", but sets a variable and requires an argument

Try to come up with a command that works first, then use it in a program.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error with the application arguments you are passing wherebye the process the application you are launching is not completing its job due to an error in that applications code or arguments. WaitForExit() will simply do exactly as the method suggest if the target process you launched hangs for whatever reason so will your application.